# PHP process form even with errors

Tags: php, html, validation

I have a processing file to validate and email a contact form from my website. Everything works well as far as sending the data, but it's not handling any errors correctly. Right now if a required field is empty, it should not allow a message to be sent. But as it is now,  it still sends the message. I'm not sure how to resolve this issue so any help is appreciated.

Here's my php

```
    <?php 
if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST') && (!empty ($_POST['action']))):

if (isset ($_POST['myname'])){$myname=$_POST['myname'];}
if (isset ($_POST['myphone'])){$myphone=$_POST['myphone'];}
if (isset ($_POST['myemail'])){$myemail=$_POST['myemail'];}
if (isset ($_POST['job'])){$job=$_POST['job'];}
if (isset ($_POST['comments'])){
    $comments= filter_var($_POST['comments'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);}

$formerrors = false;



      if($myname === '') :
      $err_myname = '<div class="error"> Sorry, your name is rquired</div>';
      endif;    

      if($myphone === ''):
      $err_myphone = '<div class="error"> Sorry, your phone number is rquired</div>';
      endif;    

      if($myemail === ''):
      $err_myemaile =  '<div class="error"> Sorry, your email is rquired</div>';
      endif;    

      if($job === ''):
      $err_job =  '<div class="error"> Sorry, your business is rquired</div>';
      endif;    



if (!($formerrors)) :
$to = "email@email.com";
$subject = " Request from $myname";

$message = "A new show and tell request from:\n
            $myname \n
            $myemail\n
            $myphone\n
            $job\n
            $comments\n";
$replyto = "From: $myemail";


if(mail($to, $subject, $message)):
    $msg ="Thanks for filling out our form";
    else:
    $msg = "There was a problem sending the message";
    endif; //mail data

endif; //check errors

endif; //form submitted

?>
```

If I need to post any more information, such as the actual html, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting `$formerrors=true` when errors are encountered, so it is always set to false and the mail is always sent.

Try something like this:

```
if($myname === '') :
  $err_myname = '<div class="error"> Sorry, your name is rquired</div>';
  $formerrors=true;
endif;
```